# Rails 6 gemfile.lock removed, generate it again

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I remove te gemfile.lock because is corrupted, but now i can use bundle

```
The deployment setting requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control
before deploying.
```

how i re gen the gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, run `bundle install` again, it will create a new Gemfile.lock

Comment: i'm had lock bundle on development, when i unlock this works